# Aggregate based on elements in the formula

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

I have a rate formula, which changes with each model. So, I want the aggregate function to check the number of elements in the rate formula and then run the aggregate function accordingly.

```
mtcars$rate_1 = mtcars$mpg - mtcars$cyl - mtcars$disp

rate_1 = "mpg - cyl - disp"
open.rate = unlist(strsplit(rate_1,"-",fixed = TRUE))

or 

mtcars$rate_1 = mtcars$mpg - mtcars$cyl - mtcars$disp - mtcars$hp
rate_1 = "mpg - cyl - disp - hp"
open.rate = unlist(strsplit(rate_1,"-",fixed = TRUE))

if(length(open.rate == 3)){
data_plot = mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% summarise(
  ####### Rates #######
  mpg = weighted.mean(eval(parse(text=mpg)),wt, na.rm = TRUE),
  cyl = weighted.mean(eval(parse(text=cyl)),wt, na.rm = TRUE),
  disp = weighted.mean(eval(parse(text=disp)),wt, na.rm = TRUE)
) 
} else {
data_plot = mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% summarise(
  ####### Rates #######
  mpg = weighted.mean(eval(parse(text=mpg)),wt, na.rm = TRUE),
  cyl = weighted.mean(eval(parse(text=cyl)),wt, na.rm = TRUE),
  disp = weighted.mean(eval(parse(text=disp)),wt, na.rm = TRUE),
  hp = weighted.mean(eval(parse(text=hp)),wt, na.rm = TRUE)
) 
}
```

The rate equation can have any number of elements. Depending on the number of elements, the aggregation needs to have the same number of elements. My aim is to write one function which takes care of that, instead of writing multiple if-else conditions.

Is there a way I can do it, without having to write the code twice for two different rates?

My solution is:

```
aggdata <- mtcars[, "carb"]
for(i in compratelist){
    print(i)
    data = mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% summarise(
    eval(parse(text = paste0(i,"_mean = weighted.mean(eval(parse(text = ", i,")),wt, na.rm = TRUE)")))
    )
    colnames(data)[2] <- i
    data <- as.data.frame(data)
    aggdata <- left_join(aggdata, data,  by = "carb")
  }
```

Comment: Why are you calling `eval` + `parse`? Also, why not run `weighted.mean` on all fields? Where do you use *open.rate*? You can certainly run this is a loop for *open.rate_list*. Your end needs is unclear though.

Comment: @Parfait chat room?

Comment: @Parfait updated. Does it make more sense now? Also, I use eval parse as the variables can change, this is just an example.

Comment: why would you pass input in this format? `"mpg - cyl - disp"` ? pass it as individual string or symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
aggdata <- mtcars[, "carb"]
for(i in compratelist){
    print(i)
    data = mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% summarise(
    eval(parse(text = paste0(i,"_mean = weighted.mean(eval(parse(text = ", i,")),wt, na.rm = TRUE)")))
    )
    colnames(data)[2] <- i
    data <- as.data.frame(data)
    aggdata <- left_join(aggdata, data,  by = "carb")
  }
```